# Java Regex to find in a Text all the possible pairs of a list

Tags: java, regex

I have a List of Strings containing names and surnames and i have a free text.

```
List<String> names; // contains: "jon", "snow", "arya", "stark", ...
String text = "jon snow and stark arya";
```

I have to find all the names and surnames, possibly with a Java Regex (so using Pattern and Matcher objects). So i want something like:

```
List<String> foundNames; // contains: "jon snow", "stark arya"
```

I have done this 2 possible ways but without using Regex, they are not static beacause part of a NameFinder class that have a list "names" that contains all the names.

```
public List<String> findNamePairs(String text) {
    List<String> foundNamePairs = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> names = this.names;
    text = text.toLowerCase();

    for (String name : names) {
        String nameToSearch = name + " ";
        int index = text.indexOf(nameToSearch);
        if (index != -1) {
            String textSubstring = text.substring(index + nameToSearch.length());
            for (String nameInner : names) {
                if (name != nameInner && textSubstring.startsWith(nameInner)) {
                    foundNamePairs.add(name + " " + nameInner);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    removeDuplicateFromList(foundNamePairs);

    return foundNamePairs;
}
```

or in a worse (very bad) way (creating all the possible pairs):

```
public List<String> findNamePairsInTextNotOpt(String text) {
    List<String> foundNamePairs = new ArrayList<String>();
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    List<String> pairs = getNamePairs(this.names);

    for (String name : pairs) {
        if (text.contains(name)) {
            foundNamePairs.add(name);
        }
    }

    removeDuplicateFromList(foundNamePairs);

    return foundNamePairs;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Why would you use regex to do that?

Comment: @JohnBellinger, I'll try to explain better in a moment. However, i need to do what I did in a "normal" method with Java Regex.

Comment: @arizzle because my professor asked to do that in this way, I'm disappointed too :V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regex using the list of names and then use find to find the names. To ensure you don't have duplicates, you can check if the name is already in the list of found names. The code would look like this.

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("jon", "snow", "stark", "arya");
String text = "jon snow and Stark arya and again Jon Snow";

StringBuilder regexBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i += 2) {
    regexBuilder.append("(")
        .append(names.get(i))
        .append(" ")
        .append(names.get(i + 1))
        .append(")");
    if (i != names.size() - 2) regexBuilder.append("|");
}

System.out.println(regexBuilder.toString());

Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(regexBuilder.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(text);

List<String> found = new ArrayList<>();

int start = 0;
while (matcher.find(start)) {
    String match = matcher.group().toLowerCase();

    if (!found.contains(match)) found.add(match);
    start = matcher.end();
}

for (String s : found) System.out.println("found: " + s);
```

If you want to be case sensitive just remove the flag in `Pattern.compile()`. If all matches have the same capitalization you can omit the `toLowerCase()` in the while loop as well.

But make sure that the list contains a multiple of 2 as list elements (name and surname) as the for-loop will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` otherwise. Also the order matters in my code. It will only find the name pairs in the order they occur in the list. If you want to have both orders, you can change the regex generation accordingly.

Edit: As it is unknown whether a name is a surname or name and which build a name/surname pair, the regex generation must be done differently.

```
StringBuilder regexBuilder = new StringBuilder("(");

for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    regexBuilder.append("(")
            .append(names.get(i))
            .append(")");
    if (i != names.size() - 1) regexBuilder.append("|");
}

regexBuilder.append(") ");
regexBuilder.append(regexBuilder);
regexBuilder.setLength(regexBuilder.length() - 1);


System.out.println(regexBuilder.toString());
```

This regex will match any of the given names followed by a space and then again any of the names.

Comment: thank you for the help, I didn't specified very well that in my list I have names and surnames mixed. 
So the list can be:
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("name1", "name2", "surname2", "surname1");

So I can't put in the regex (element1 element2) | (element3 element4), I have to put all the possible combinations and I am afraid that it can be very slow.

Comment: Well you have to test all combinations, as you have no information about which name and surname go together, as well as not knowing if a name is a name or a surname. I will add a section to the answer about generating a regex for this.